# Event REST Api Call for Azure Iot Central

Tags: azure, cloud, rest, azure-iot-central

Is it possible to get the Event log in Azure IOT Central without exporting your data to Azure Event Hubs, Azure Service Bus, Azure Blob storage, or Webhook like Pipidream?
I know its possible to get properties and telemetries with REST API using Azure CLI like below but as for event I only manage to get one event which is the latest event as below.
Is it possible to get a list of event log with start time and end time like other cloud such as Telit or Thingsboard?

Properties:
az rest -m get -u http://myserver.azureiotcentral.com/api/preview/devices/mydevice/components/template1/properties --headers Authorization="SharedAccessSignature sr=604e72d5-0ca3-4dc9-9e7c-08a78c5d2595&sig=sA3bNciO%2B8CSk6%2FQIBU7IjVBPVR6QDdfV3LKQxT93W0%3D&skn=TestingBB&se=1635420831857"

Event:
az rest -m get -u http://myserver.azureiotcentral.com/api/preview/devices/mydevice/components/template1/telemetry/eventGeneric --headers Authorization="SharedAccessSignature sr=604e72d5-0ca3-4dc9-9e7c-08a78c5d2595&sig=sA3bNciO%2B8CSk6%2FQIBU7IjVBPVR6QDdfV3LKQxT93W0%3D&skn=TestingBB&se=1635420831857"

Comment: Related thread to help answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/439003/index.html